# SonarQube: Cannot deactivate rule with missing quality profile

Tags: sonarqube

I have a rule in my SonarQube that has no Quality Profile associated with it in the search list (The red box [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHnQG.png)). When I try to change it I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8trN.png), and when i try to click the Deactivate button, nothing happens.

I tried adding a Quality Profile with that name and then changing it, but I think that name might refer to the ID instead of the readable name so that didn't work.

How would I go about removing a rule that has a missing Quality Profile?

Comment: Got the same - Mithfindels anwser below solved my problem, would you mind accepting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out.

I just had to manually insert a new row into the rules_profiles database table with a key that matched the one in the error. Then go back into the online interface and delete that profile.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to fix these kinds of issues is to stop your instance, clear `$SQ_HOME/data/es` and restart your instance. This will ensure that the ElasticSearch index of rules is in sync with the database state.