# Unable to deactivate a particular rule -- Quality profile not found

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube5.1.2

When trying to deactivate `common-java:InsufficientBranchCoverage` I'm getting an error: `Quality profile not found: java-sonar-way-03260`

Nothing appears in the logs.

I can deactivate other rules without problem but this one just gives an error.

Possibly duplicate of: [SonarQube: Cannot deactivate rule with missing quality profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28199435)

Comment: Did you try the solution proposed in the question you linked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it with the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28212161/1237617), but the person who asked that question didn't accept it and is not responding.